# set values of a struct pointer to a struct

Tags: pointers

Is it possible to set the values of a struct pointer in a struct? I get an error and cannot typecast myStruct* into myStruct.

```
typedef struct {
   int foo;
   int bar;
} myStruct;

int main() {

myStruct *pS;

myStruct S1 = {0,0};

myStruct S2;

pS = S1;

S2 = pS;   // I get an error there, cannot set struct pointer to a   struct
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your example, you have pointer `pS` and regular variable `S1`.

> A pointer is a variable that stores the memory address as its value.

> Variable is the name of memory location.

So, the difference between regular variable is that variable stores *value* of an object, but pointer stores *memory address* of an object.

There are operators which allow getting object's address and getting object value by it's address:

- Address-of operator `&`. `&a` will return address of object `a`.
- Dereference operator `*`. `*p` will return object stored by address `p`.

Thus, in your code you should get two errors:

```
pS = S1; // error: Trying to assign struct value to a pointer

S2 = pS; // error: Trying to assign pointer to a struct value
```

To fix this, you should assign **address** to a `pS` and **value** to `S2`

```
typedef struct {
   int foo;
   int bar;
} myStruct;

int main() {

myStruct *pS;

myStruct S1 = {0,0};

myStruct S2;

pS = &S1; // getting address of S1

S2 = *pS; // getting value stored by address pS
}
```